# How to avoid @click on only one child component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, stoppropagation

For example if I click on all the v-card I am redirecting to an other link BUT if I click on the title `World of the Day` and only on the `title` I don't want to do nothing. How to avoid to be redirected when clicking on `title` ?

[image]

```
template>
  <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="344"
    @click="goToAnOtherLink"
  >
    <v-card-text>
      <div>Word of the Day</div>
      <p class="display-1 text--primary">
        be•nev•o•lent
      </p>
      <p>adjective</p>
      <div class="text--primary">
        well meaning and kindly.<br>
        "a benevolent smile"
      </div>
    </v-card-text>
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn
        text
        color="deep-purple accent-4"
      >
        Learn More
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the title `div` as well, and check the classes of your event's target inside the function `goToAnOtherLink`. Then you can use `stopPropagation()` along with the custom code you have in that function.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {},
  methods: {
    goToAnOtherLink(e) {
      if (e.target.classList.contains("title") || e.target.classList.contains("display-1")) {
        e.stopPropagation()
        console.log("Cancelled Navigation!")
      } else {
        console.log("Navigated!")
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@1.5.14/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet" />

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="344" @click="goToAnOtherLink">
      <v-card-text>
        <div class="title">Word of the Day</div>
        <p class="display-1 text--primary">
          be•nev•o•lent
        </p>
        <p>adjective</p>
        <div class="text--primary">
          well meaning and kindly.<br> "a benevolent smile"
        </div>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-btn text color="deep-purple accent-4">
          Learn More
        </v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: @Ady642 Glad to assist :)

Answer (score 2):

If it's *only* the `title`, use the `stop` event modifier. This is **easier** than having the logic in the method.

```
<v-app>
    <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="344" @click="goToAnOtherLink">
        <v-card-text>
            <div class="title" @click.stop>Word of the Day</div>
            <p class="display-1 text--primary"> be•nev•o•lent </p>
            <p>adjective</p>
            <div class="text--primary"> well meaning and kindly.<br> "a benevolent smile" </div>
        </v-card-text>
        <v-card-actions>
            <v-btn text color="deep-purple accent-4"> Learn More </v-btn>
        </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</v-app>
```

https://codeply.com/p/2ExpE6PF6F

Comment: Thank you ! I didn' know that we can use `@click.stop`alone like that .
Oh I can't put the answer green for both responses... 
What I prefer in the JS methods is that We can check the class name and exclude directly all elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your v-card in a div and use absolute positioning to place the title; so that the title is in "front" of the v-card thus clicking on it does nothing.

Pseudo-code

```
<div>
   <span>Word of the day</span> <!-- use absolute to position inside the div -->
   <v-card></v-card>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah ! I don't like to use absolute , there is no other solution ?

Comment: Or you could use @anurag's answer above. There's nothing wrong with absolute positioning if you use it correctly. Personally I would take absolute positioning in css over additional JS code. The choice is yours.

Comment: Yes thank you for your response . If we use absolute position , the template can be difficul to read I think.